# How can an Eclipse TextEditorAction know what project the current file is in?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm working on an inherited codebase for a somewhat complex Eclipse plugin that is used to view and edit files in a custom specification language.

It doesn't matter what the language is, but it has functional similarities to CORBA IDL and XML XSD.  In one module, I can "import" another module, and associate a prefix to be used with the references to those imported components, to prevent name conflicts.

The plugin has defined a "OpenDeclarationAction" that is supposed to work exactly like the similar action in the JDT. When executed on the reference to a component, it will bring up the module where that component is defined, and put the cursor on the definition of the component.

I noticed that the plugin has a bug, where if there are two different projects in the workspace with two files of the same name, in this custom language, when I execute "OpenDeclarationAction", it will only open the module that was first found while indexing the workspace, instead of preferring the module in the same project as the original module.

When I looked at the internal index of components, I saw that it does not which project each module and component came from, so I figured fixing this would be easy, as when the action executes, I can compare the current project with the project of the entry in the index, and only use it if they match.

However, what I realized is that in my custom TextEditorAction, which is instantiated from my custom "org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor" subclass, although the "index search" function that I use can accept a "project" parameter, I can find no way from inside the TextEditorAction to know what the current project is.

For instance, here is an excerpt from my "TextEditor" subclass, where I create the TextEditorAction subclass (OpenDeclarationAction):

```
    @Override
protected void createActions() {

    super.createActions();
    IAction action = null;
    ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(YangEditorMessages.getBundleName());

    action = new TextOperationAction(bundle, "ContentFormat_", this, ISourceViewer.FORMAT); //$NON-NLS-1$
    action.setActionDefinitionId(IYangEditorActionDefinitionIds.FORMAT);
    setAction("FormatDocument", action); //$NON-NLS-1$

    action = getAction(ITextEditorActionConstants.CONTENT_ASSIST_CONTEXT_INFORMATION);

    action = new OpenDeclarationAction(bundle, "OpenDeclaration_", this); //$NON-NLS-1$
    action.setActionDefinitionId(IYangEditorActionDefinitionIds.OPEN_DECLARATION);
    setAction("OpenDeclaration", action); //$NON-NLS-1$
    markAsStateDependentAction("OpenDeclaration", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
    markAsSelectionDependentAction("OpenDeclaration", true); //$NON-NLS-1$
```

and here is some of my OpenDeclarationAction class:

```
public class OpenDeclarationAction extends TextEditorAction {

public OpenDeclarationAction(ResourceBundle bundle, String prefix, ITextEditor editor) {
    super(bundle, prefix, editor);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    YangEditor editor = (YangEditor) getTextEditor();

    try {
        ISelection selection = editor.getSelectionProvider().getSelection();
        Module module = YangParserUtil.parseYangFile(editor.getDocument().get().toCharArray());
        ASTNode node = module.getNodeAtPosition(((ITextSelection) selection).getOffset());
```

I've explored all of the parameters sent to the OpenDeclarationAction class, including all of their "get" methods, to see if there was any chain of calls that could lead to the current project.  That appears to be a dead end.  If the project is available, I imagine there must be some "reverse" data structure somewhere that will give me the project from some other piece of data that I have.

I know that something like this is possible, because I experimented with the same situation with identical Java classes in two different projects.  Eclipse always sent me to the class in the same project as the reference.

What could I do to set this up so this will do what I want?

Comment: What type of IEditorInput does your editor work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ITextEditor.getEditorInput()](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart.html#getEditorInput()) may contain a descendant of `IEditorInput` which has [IFile](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IFileEditorInput.html) or [URI](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IURIEditorInput.html) information. Given these, you can derive IProject by either invoking `IFile.getProject()` of parsing URI.

Comment: Ok, this is promising.  I found that at runtime it's a FileEditorInput, which leads to the project.  However, my first test after plugging this in still found the component in the other project, so I have to look closer at the data.

Comment: I found that that discrepancy was due to an experiment I had forgotten about, by setting the test project to also depend on another project, where it eventually found the component in. It's good that I saw that, because now this verifies that I can get components from dependent projects also.